# JavaScript Clicked Outside of Element

Tags: javascript, html, events

I know with jQuery it is quite easy to see if a user has clicked outside of a particular element and then react to it, much like how clicking outside of an open drop down menu will close it.

I am trying to achieve something similar with  JavaScript alone, no jQuery. Here is my current code:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var nav = document.querySelectorAll('ul li.current_page_item');
  var navList = nav[0].parentNode;

//Open the navigation menu list
  nav[0].onclick = function() {
    navList.className = 'open';
  }
}
```

As of now, the code will apply a class of `open` to an unordered list if its child element `li.current_page_item` is clicked on.

I would like to trigger an event (to remove the `open` class) if the user clicks outside of the `li.current_page_item` list item.

Could someone show how I could listen for then react to an event that would do something like this **with JavaScript alone**?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Well think about how you'd do it _with_ jQuery, and then apply the same principle in plain JS: you'd probably start by binding a click handler to the document, because that would catch clicks outside the menu item...

Comment: Yes I know. I edited my previous comment a little after you first saw it, but even the original version didn't say "use jQuery", it only asked you to think about how you'd do it with jQuery (in the hope that that would give you a clue about how to do it without - the same principles apply either way).

Comment: @spryno724 he means that, as you know jQuery, you could apply same logic to solve the problem with plain JavaScript. I.e., you `addEventLister` to the `document` in pure javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add click on the document that will close the div,  and remember to stopPropagation in the `li` handler or it will propagate to the document as well.

```
document.onclick = function(e) {
  navList.className = 'close';
}

nav[0].onclick = function(e) {
  navList.className = 'open';
  e.stopPropagation(); // <----
}
```

Comment: Yessss! Totally didn't think of `stopPropagation()`. Thank you!